# What does "unsaved photos from Messages" mean?

Tags: photos, bug

When I try to favorite a collection that Photos on my iPhone recommends to me, I get a message saying that I have "unsaved photos from Messages which you need to save before continuing", and am unable to proceed:

[image]

What photos? Where can I find them? What does this mean? How do I proceed?

Comment: I got the exact error message when I try to create album. did you find the real reason for this error message?

Answer (score -1):

There are photos in the album or memory that were sent to you via messages. You need to find those photos and delete the message the came in. This will cause the error to go away

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).